# How to show a message to the user after printing a Jasper Report

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jasper-reports

I have one page that should do it:

1. Process clients data
2. Generate a jasper report
3. Send emails to the clients

I want to show user a message "Email sent correctly" or "Email not sent"

I search for a way extensively, but I see that this is impossible, because the response is flushed when I generate the report.

But, doing more research I found this class: [ServletResponseWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponseWrapper.html) that may be helpful, which I can change the content of the Response object. But I don't realize how can I do this. So I would like some suggestions on how to use this class to do what I like (if it is possible) or maybe other suggestions to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a value the session, but you will need to compute the response in order to save it, thus refreshing the page you can use this value to show/hide a message telling whether or not the email has been succesfully sent or not.

If you have a backing bean you can manage a `boolean sent = true/false`, and use ajax to refresh partially your page - a panel for example, that tells the user the outcome of the operation.